# Retrieving who created a meeting "on behalf of" in EWS SOAP service

Tags: soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've been working in a meeting management app using EWS SOAP service (Exchange 2010 SP1), but for meetings created on behalf of a certain user I cannot know who is this user when I try to get the meeting data through EWS SOAP.

In Outlook (2010 specifically) I can see the name of the account who has acting in behalf of another account on a meeting request for accept or rejection (e.g. **Some User ; on behalf of; Another User** ), then I want to retrieve the same information through EWS.

I tried to retrieve the meeting information using the example of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn439786(v=exchg.80).aspx changing the Element IdOnly by AllProperties
but I cannot see the property that define who acted in behalf of this account

Is there any way to obtain this user's email or name?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to check this on the meeting request, not the appointment. Check the From and Sender, as I recall the Sender would be the delegate, and the From would be the delegator (though I may have them switched :))